# Centralised Second Level Cache

Tags: java, jpa, ehcache, hazelcast, terracotta

We're trying to horizontally scale a JPA based application, but have encountered issues with the second level cache of JPA. We've looked at several solutions (EhCache, Terracotta, Hazelcast) but couldn't seem to find the right solution. Basically what we want to achieve is to have multiple application servers all pointing to a single cache server that serves as the JPA's second level cache.

From a non java perspective, it would look like several PHP servers all pointing to one centralised memcache server as it's cache service. Is this currently possible with Java?

Thanks

Comment: May I know why Ehcache/terracotta failed the evaluation?

Comment: Well we don't want to replace the L1 cache with ehcache, we just want a centralised L2 cache. So I was wondering if we can retain our default L1 cache which is already built into the JPA provider, but just swap out the L2 cache.

Comment: L1 cache is tied to your JPA session. That is sole responsibility of the JPA provider. Ehcache will not mess with that. Ehcache will be used by the JPA provider as L2 cache ONLY. And it you want distributed caching, there is terracota.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, maybe you can shed a bit more light regarding the architecture diagram in this url (http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.4/terracotta/architecture)

Comment: I had to put the details as an answer, because it was not readable as comment. Pls check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This is in response to the comment above.***

1. Terracotta will be deployed in it's own server
2. Each of the app server will have terracota drivers which will store/retrieve data to-fro terracotta server.
3. Ehcache api present in the application war, will invoke the terracota drivers to store data into terracotta server.
4. Hibernate api will maintain the L1 cache, in addition it will use the ehcache api to save/retrieve data to-fro L2 cache. Blissfully unaware about how ehcache api performs the task.